# AWS Network load balancer or EC2 Bastion host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bastion-host, network-load-balancer

One of the data providers, only offers transfer to an FTP server.

To test connection I started an FTP server in a public subnet and opened port:21 in Security Group, unfortunately the data did not reach there, so in VPC Flow Logs I checked that apart from port:21, there are other different ports that need to be opened, but they change so often that I am not able to add all of them to Security Group:
[image: VPC Flow Logs]

I want my ftp server in private subnet and some sort of network interface to handle incoming connections.

Therefore I want to set up either Network load balancer or EC2 Jump host (I need Bastion host because I don't want to assign elastic IP to another instance, just one with elastic IP and then rest of instances in private subnet).

1. Network load balancer has ports that it listens to, due to the fact that there are a lot of ports and they change, I am not able to add them all. Is there a way to bypass this?
2. The second approach is to setup an EC2 Bastion Host that would accept all connections but forward what is on port 21
   [image: EC2 Bastion host setup]

Does this even make sense? Is there any pattern that is easier?

Comment: What are the ports that frequently change used for?

Comment: Use the `PASV` command to make FTP operate in Passive mode. This will force it to only use the standard port.

Comment: @Fermin: I am not sure. But I have checked number of bytes that went through this connection and it seems that data was transfered there. Port:21 bytes_in: 950, Rest of ports bytes_in 17328.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein server configuration is not really a problem here. I want to open only port 21 in security group. I can't reconfigure source data provider. They just expect me to pass IP or DNS and don't allow specific ports.

Comment: It is actually a server configuration issue. Your server is accepting a connection on port `21` and then assigning an ephemeral port to that client and telling the client to start sending data over that specific ephemeral port.  https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43680/why-does-ftp-passive-mode-use-a-range-of-ephemeral-ports-as-opposed-to-a-single You need to configure your server to use a specific range of ports, and open all those ports in the security group https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/assigning-specific-range-ephemeral-ports-ftp

Comment: Note that this is one of the reasons nobody uses FTP anymore, along with the fact that it is completely insecure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any amount of choice of approach, commit to SFTP instead, last time I saw it it did do its job, exactly through bastion in a setup similar to yours.
https://dev.to/tanmaygi/how-to-create-a-sftp-server-on-ec2centosubuntu--1f0m